# how to use useSelector inside axios interceptors?

Tags: reactjs, axios, jwt

i am new to the react and i want to check whether access token has expired or not on every request using axios interceptors , but i am not able to retrieve access token stored inside the redux ( because i know we cant use hooks outside components ) so what could be the possible solution to retrieve access token stored in redux memory .

Here is my code

```
import axios from "axios";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/api/v1",
});

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(req => {

  // get access token stored in redux

  // decode access token

  // check if token expired 

  // if expired request new access token
  
  return req ;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import your instance of the store and the [get the state](https://redux.js.org/api/store#getstate).

```
store.getState().{reducer that contain the token}.token
```

Comment: worked ! i am profoundly indebted ....